What does the word תָּם mean when applied to Yaakov in the Torah
Yaakov is called תָּם in the Torah, Genesis 25:27. I've heard that this word can be translated as an adjective to mean "simple" (I don't speak very good Hebrew). Is this meaning of the word more slang than the actual meaning of the word? Why would Yaakov be described as simple? In English translations of the Torah, people even translate it this way. Is this in juxtaposition to Esau because of how what he was doing was a more "complicated" thing in his life, for he is described as צַיִד.
Do people actually consider Yaakov to be simple? If so, when do people consider him to become more complicated when that is after he is given a new name from Hashem?

I've seen תָּם translated several ways, and when taken together, I think you get a better understanding of the world. It means simple, innocent, complete, perfect.

I don't understand how one can be 'perfect' and 'simple' at the same time Rabbi. Can you elaborate? Would it be fair then to apply this word to Hashem?

Hashem's ways are described as "תם", but afaik the Torah never describes Hashem Himself that way. It does make sense though. Simple and perfect go well together. Consider the simple son, vs the wise son. The wise son asks a "complicated" sophisticated question: "what is the difference between edot, chukim, mishpatim". The simple son asks a much more profound and important question: "what is a mitzva". No schemes or sophistication, just an innocent attempt to understand. Asking "what is that" usually cuts right to the issue, and all the sophisticated questions fall away upon answering it

So, simple means straightforward, uncomplicated, without ulterior motives or schemes. The innocent child is simple in this way, but it is a good and Godly trait to retain throughout life - to be innocent and child-like (not childish), wholehearted and perfect. Complete - haven't lost, through growing up, any of the wonderful treasures and traits our pure souls are born with, haven't developed any cynicism or distrust. This is Yaakov. He stayed at home and learned Torah all day, didn't need to go out to "the field" and live a complicated life, or make a name for himself

@RabbiKaii Please see דרך עץ החיים: עיון ה׳ by Rabbi Moshe Chaim Luzzato. It deals with this subject explicitly.

The original meaning for the word תם - wholesome, as explained by Rashi on the verse Devarim 18:13:

You must be wholehearted/perfect (תמים) with your God יהוה, i.e. walk before him whole-heartedly, put thy hope in Him and do not attempt to investigate the future, but whatever it may be that comes upon thee accept it whole-heartedly, and then thou shalt be with Him and become His portion (Sifrei Devarim 173:3).

There are also explanations based on reading the word תם backwards, i.e. מת - dead. I.e. תם is the opposite in every respect of being dead.
In life mostly simple people tend to be wholehearted (hence the modern usage and usage in Passover Hagadah). However, Yaakov avinu was very a smart and learned person for his time, and he remained wholesome despite his trials in life.
The etimilogical dictionary by Ernest Klein translates תם as

1 complete, perfect.     2 innocent, artless.   PBH  3 naive.   PBH  4 without blemish.  [From תמם.] Derivative: תַּמּוּת.

where PBH = Post Biblical Hebrew. Perhaps, the post biblical meaning has been acquired due to Passover Haggadah, where the 3rd son is asking a question, which appears simpler compared to those of the first two sons. Talmud Yerushalmi Pesachim 10:4 names the sons as

תַּנֵּי רִבִּי חִייָה. כְּנֶגֶד אַרְבָּעָה בָּנִים דִּיבְּרָה תוֹרָה. בֶּן חָכָם בֶּן רָשָׁע בֶּן טִיפֵּשׁ בֶּן שֶׁאֵינוֹ יוֹדֵעַ לִשְׁאָל.
Rebbi Ḥiyya stated “The Torah spoke about Four Children, a wise child, a wicked child, a stupid child, and a child who does not know how to ask.

where, the word טִיפֵּשׁ means stupid. The same wording is used in Mekhilta d'Rabbi Yishmael 13:14:1 quoted by Rashi in the commentary on Chumash where he explains the verse quoted by the child in the Haggada Shemos 13:14:

מה זאת WHAT IS THIS? — This is the question of a dull child (תינוק טפש) who has not sufficient understanding to question very profoundly and who therefore asks in an indefinite fashion, “What is this?” In another passage (Deuteronomy 6:20) it states, “[When thy son asketh thee…], What mean the testimonies and the statutes and the judgments … [which the Lord our God hath commanded you?]” This, however, is the question of a wise son. The Torah in mentioning four different explanations of the Passover sacrifice-rite to be given by a father to his children, is speaking in reference to four different types of son: the wicked son (Shemos 12:25 and in the second half ofShemos 13:8), and one who has not sufficient understanding how to ask (טִיפֵּשׁ, in the first half of Shemos 13:8), and one who asks in an indefinite manner (Shemos 13:14), and one who asks in a wise fashion (Devarim 6:20) (cf. Mekhilta d'Rabbi Yishmael 13:14:1; Jerusalem Talmud Pesachim 10:4).

The Passover Haggadah changed the wording, however, the old understanding continued:

כְּנֶגֶד אַרְבָּעָה בָנִים דִּבְּרָה תוֹרָה: אֶחָד חָכָם, וְאֶחָד רָשָׁע, וְאֶחָד תָּם, וְאֶחָד שֶׁאֵינוֹ יוֹדֵעַ לִשְׁאוֹל.
The Torah relates to four types of sons – one who is wise, one who is wicked, one tam - with a simple nature, and one who does not know how to ask.

Vilna Gaon in his commentary on Haggadah mentions that this is a simple understanding. The message of the Haggada is deeper. I.e. the sons are not grouped linearly by their ability to ask a question, but in pairs:

חכם - a wise son vs. שֶׁאֵינוֹ יוֹדֵעַ לִשְׁאוֹל - one who cannot ask;
רָשָׁע - a wicked son vs. תָּם - a wholesome son

Indeed, a wholesome son is not going to strike others with the most complex question: he is interested in the whole experience of the seder, just like the wicked son seeks to separate himself from the seder. Perhaps, that was the intent to change the word טִיפֵּשׁ to תָּם.

Are you able to explain where the meaning of the word 'simple' has come from as applied to this word? Is it a bit incorrect to use the word in this way?

@RabbiKaii you are correct, the second is found in Shir haShirim 5:2 when referred to a young woman. Regarding Yaakov it is used as אִ֣ישׁ תָּ֔ם, where אִ֣ישׁ is man of virtue.
